# How to make Jira query

Tags: python, tcl, jira

Title might be misleading. I know how to make a jira query, but I want to know that is it possible to make a query using external scripts made form python or Tcl. We have the issue number and the URL, and using the scripts, can we get details of that particular issue number? Like the status, fix versions, etc.? Any heads up would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JIRA Python library at http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ has examples of how to do this